# Why did git create a master folder in my working folder?

Tags: git

My git folder looks like:

```
c:\mygits\project1.git\
```

So I went into that project1.git folder, and then did a clone.

For some reason (is this normal?), it created a master folder which I am forced to go into.

```
c:\mygits\project1.git\master\
```

if I just to to the project1.git folder, it says no repo is here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you clone it? It looks like you have done

```
git clone c:\... master
```

The last term creates a target directory.

Comment: I thought master was the name of the branch I wanted to clone.

Comment: @mrblah: A clone will pull in ALL branches.  All history and branches are stored locally in the .git directory.

Answer (score 5):

Almost always directories called `project.git` are used for *bare* repositories, so if you are using it for or to contain a non-bare repository you will probably cause some confusion.

Typically for a clone, you want to go into the directory in which you want to create the cloned repository and do:

```
git clone url://to/project.git
```

git will create the directory for the `project` repository for you, you don't have to create it yourself. The name chosen by git is the last element of the url path without a `.git` or a `/.git`, if found.

git will fetch all remote branches and create you a local branch based on the `HEAD` (default branch) of the remote repository. This is often called `master`.

After making the clone you can create local branches based of any other remote branches if you wish using the `git branch` command.

e.g. create a local branch based on the remote repositories `other` branch.

```
git branch other origin/other
```

If you want git to create the project in a differently named repository directory you can supply this as an extra parameter to git clone.

e.g.

```
git clone url://to/project.git project-clone-2
```

Again, I recommend that you avoid directories ending with `.git` unless you are intentionally creating a `bare` clone.

```
git clone --bare url://to/project.git alt-project.git
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you include an extra master parameter at the end when you cloned your repository? The parameter after the clone url is the local directory name.

```
git clone repository directory
```

directory is optional. It will default to the repository name if omitted.

Git clone [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)